# Memory leak during orientation change with inner class

Tags: android

I encounter a memory leak problem on the orientation change of my Activity. With the android tools and the Memory Analysis Perspective (http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2010/01/attacking-memory-problems-on-android.html) I finally found the following problem:

During orientation change I save the data I need into an Inner class as you can see in the folowing code:

```
public class TestOrientation extends Activity {

    private ActivityData mData;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
        ...
        mData = (ActivityData) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return new ActivityData(dataToSave1, dataToSave2);
    }

    private class ActivityData {

        public int mDataToSave1;
        public String mDataToSave2;

        public ActivityData(int dataToSave1, String dataToSave2) {
            mDataToSave1 = dataToSave1;
            mDataToSave2 = dataToSave2;
        }
    }
}
```

In the memory Memory Analysis Perspective I can see that the attribute mData keeps a reference to the activity Context so it's never deallocated. After a few orientation change I have a recursive reference:

[image: sreenshot of MAP]

To solve it I've declared the ActivityData in a separate file, but if somebody can explain me why I encounter this problem I would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your private class (ActivityData) static. Inner non-static classes keep a reference of their outer class.

Comment: I don't want to make the ActivityData class Static but after reading your post I've been on the Java doc and in the Nested Classes page( http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html ) :
"As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class..."
So that’s why it keeps a reference on my activity.
Thanks

Comment: There is no harm in making ActivityData static, except losing access to the enclosing class, which you don't need anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume foo is your second argument.

Perhaps foo is a String from within your context (such as someTextView.getText() )? Try passing foo.clone() or simply new String(foo);